# Will not print True or False

Tags: python, python-3.x

My challenge is to inspect an IP address and mask number, then decide if another IP address is on that local network.

Considering the IP block 10.0.0.0 and a subnet mask of 255.0.0.0, we can represent this like so: 10.0.0.0/8 (this is called CIDR notation).

As an example, the address 10.21.8.15 would be on the local network. The address 11.34.57.1 would not.

Input:
Two lines of input as follows:

IPv4 Network block in standard CIDR notation
IPv4 Address to Check

Output:
If the IP address is in the subnet defined by the CIDR, print "True". Otherwise, print "False".

Test 1
Test Input:

10.10.0.0/8

10.22.11.16

Expected Output:

True

Test 2
Test Input:

10.10.231.124/16

10.22.11.16

Expected Output:

False

Test 3
Test Input:

192.168.0.0/18

192.168.16.1

Expected Output:
True

```py
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end="")
import ipaddress

network_block = input()
ip_address = input()

subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(network_block)
ip = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_address)

if ip in subnet:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

When I run this it is only printing the input of the IP addresses and not whether or not it is True or False.

Comment: That first `for` loop runs forever, taking input and doing nothing with it except printing.  None of your code that has anything to do with IP addresses ever gets executed.

Comment: how can I get it to read the inputs without running forever? I need it to read the input and run my code to determine if true or false @jasonharper

Comment: You are getting your actual input via `input()`.  Get rid of the `for` loop that is preventing you from ever reaching that code.

Comment: I removed the for loop and now the code doesn't even read the Test Input IP's. the output results in (None) @jasonharper

Comment: Hardcode the input which isn't handled correctly. That way, one possible failure source is eliminated automatically. This is also part of extracting a [mcve], which is an actual prerequisite for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, I hard coded the inputs but the concept should be the same if take a user input. Mask out the host bits with `False` in the `ipaddress.ip_network` command.

Code:

```
import sys
import ipaddress
nblocks = ['10.10.0.0/8', '10.10.231.124/16', '192.168.0.0/18']
ips = ['10.22.11.16', '10.22.11.16', '192.168.16.1']
for b,i in zip(nblocks, ips):
    subnet = ipaddress.ip_network(b, False)
    ip = ipaddress.ip_address(i)
    if ip in subnet:
            print("True")
    else:
            print("False")
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```